# Sharing Model between directives and nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have several items in my application that depend on others.

### Example Nested Selects:

```
<!-- optionsa is built from ajax -->
<select ng-model="current_optiona" ng-options="a as a.name for a in optionsa"></select>
<!-- optionsb is built when current_optiona change -->
<select ng-model="current_optionb" ng-options="b as b.name for b in optionsb"></select>
<!-- optionsc is built when current_optionb change -->
<select ng-model="current_optionc" ng-options="c as c.name for c in optionsc"></select>
```

**Problem #1** The problem here is that I have to implement the methods and model of each of the select in each of the controllers

**Solution P#1** move the methods and model to service

**Problem #2** if I wanted to show on one controller the nested select several times, all lists (optionsa, optionsb, optionsc) contain the same

**Problem #3** not always are the same three select, can be only two them or mixed with other

**Proposed solution** constructing a directive for creating independent models for sharing and sub ​​directives that allow choose to select display. the main idea here is one directive watch and popule all lists (optionsa, optionsb and optionsc) the inner directives or selects only the directive scope for get the options and can use ng-model for share with the controller

```
<filters>
    <select ng-model="current_optiona" ng-options="a as a.name for a in mistery.optionsa"></select>
    <select ng-model="current_optionb" ng-options="b as b.name for b in mistery.optionsb"></select>
</filters>
```

### The Question(s)

with this solution i can use many filters but

- How i can share models between directives?
- How i can access to parent directive model (`mistery` variable) from directive?
- How i can access (and modify) to controller models from directives?

### Update #1

this is a early experience

### `directive-filter.coffee`

```
app
.directive 'filters' , ->
  restrict: 'E'
  transclude: true
  replace: true
  scope:          # if enable the scope the
    ns: '=model'  # sub directives can access
  template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
  controller: ($scope, MyAPI) ->
    $scope.ns =
      optionsa: []
      optionsb: []
      optionsc: []
      optiona: {}
      optionb: {}
      optionc: {}

    MyAPI.$watch 'ns.objecta', (values) ->
      $scope.ns.optionsa = values
    MyAPI.$watch 'ns.objectb', (values) ->
      $scope.ns.optionsb = values

    $scope.$watch 'ns.optionsa', (valuea) ->
      MyAPI.get 'objectb', valuea.id

    MyAPI.get 'objecta'

.directive 'optiona', ->
   restrict: 'E'
   require: '^filters'
   templateUrl: 'directive.optiona.html'

.directive 'optionb', ->
   restrict: 'E'
   require: '^filters'
   templateUrl: 'directive.optionb.html'
```

### `Templates`

```
<!-- directive.optiona.html -->

<label>Select option a</label>
<select
    ng-model="$parent.ns.optiona"
    ng-options="i as i.name for i in $parent.ns.optionsa">
</select>

<!-- directive.optionb.html -->

<label>Select option a</label>
<select
    ng-model="$parent.ns.optionb"
    ng-options="i as i.name for i in $parent.ns.optionsb">
</select>
```

### Mode of use

```
<filters>
  <optiona></optiona>
  <optionb></optionb>
</filters>
```

the previous sample solves all except when i attach a `scope` to the `filters` directive the  subdirectives stop of work. how i can share the ng-model every subdirective

**Example** in the main template of my controller

```
<filters model="myfilter">
  <optiona></optiona>
  <optionb></optionb>
</filters>
```

How can i make work this?

Comment: 1. Use an enclosing controller to house the shared model. Either data-bind the model into the directives, or just do not declare an isolate scope in your directive, and it will inherit the parents. 2. Through the inherited scope. 3. Same, via scope inheritance.

Comment: @aet please ansrwe the question and can you add an example

Comment: If you can put together a fiddle or plunkr with your problem I will be glad to see if I can make it work the way you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution: moving the select option by each filter and using the controller for update the main directive, but have a drawback each filter need a `model` attribute even if this is not used

### Mode of use

### `.coffee`

```
for directiveName in ['optiona', 'optionb']    
  do (directiveName)
    .directive 'directiveName', ->
       restrict: 'E'
       require: '^filters'
       templateUrl: 'directive.' + directiveName + '.html'
       scope: { localModel: "=model" }
       controller: ($scope) ->
          $scope.$watch 'localModel', (value) ->
              $scope.$parent.ns[directiveName] = value
```

### `templates`

```
<!-- directive.optiona.html -->

<label>Select option a</label>
<select
    ng-model="localModel"
    ng-options="i as i.name for i in $parent.ns.optionsa">
</select>

<!-- directive.optionb.html -->

<label>Select option a</label>
<select
    ng-model="localModel"
    ng-options="i as i.name for i in $parent.ns.optionsb">
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this problem is to model the data in the format that makes it easy for achieving what you are looking for.

If you model become hierarchical you may be able to achieve this without directives. Model structured as

```
$scope.optionsa=[{
                   prop1:"",
                   prop2:"", 
                   optionsb:[{
                              prop1:"",
                              optionc:[{},{}]
                            },{},{}]
                }]
```

So your select becomes

```
<select ng-model="current_optiona" ng-options="a as a.name for a in optionsa"></select>
<!-- optionsb is built when current_optiona change -->
<select ng-model="current_optionb" ng-options="b as b.name for b in current_optiona.optionsb"></select>
<!-- optionsc is built when current_optionb change -->
<select ng-model="current_optionc" ng-options="c as c.name for c in current_optionb.optionsc"></select>
```

Comment: i need a controller because i need watch values for populate correctly  each lists